# outputting the value of a resource variable in php

Tags: php

I wanted to output some scores in a rank from MySQL database with php. After my select query, I try echoing the value but all I get is RESOURCE ID 10#. This is my code:

```
$rank = mysql_query("SELECT 1+COUNT(*) FROM `class_ranking` WHERE overall_scores > (SELECT overall_scores FROM `class_ranking` WHERE ref_id='$id')");
While ($rk = mysql_fetch_array($rank)){
    echo $rk['overall_scores'];
}
```

Please I need your assistance. Thanks.

Comment: `1+COUNT(*) ` is this field name ?

Comment: what is `1+COUNT(*)` in query?

Comment: No please it is not.

Comment: The query worked when I run it in phpmyadmin SQL platform. Am now left with how to output it in a browser

Comment: I think my major problem here is the syntax to ech

Answer (score 3):

write this way `1+COUNT(*) as overall_scores`

```
$rank = mysql_query("SELECT 1+COUNT(*) as overall_scores FROM `class_ranking` WHERE overall_scores > (SELECT overall_scores FROM `class_ranking` WHERE ref_id='$id')");
While ($rk = mysql_fetch_array($rank)){
    echo $rk['overall_scores'];
}
```

Comment: Thanks very much I made the correction and it worked perfectly. Am proud to be a member of this platform.

Comment: your welcome @user3860384, if you think helpfull so accept this answer..!

Comment: How do I find the sum of first two scores from a database after ordering the scores in ascending order with php?

Answer (score 2):

Set an alias for the count:

`SELECT 1+COUNT(*)  AS overall_scores`

Answer (score 1):

To start, `SELECT 1+COUNT(*)` will return something like

```
+------------+
| 1+count(*) |
+------------+
|          4 |
+------------+
```

Therefore, this won't work

```
While ($rk = mysql_fetch_array($rank)){
    echo $rk['overall_scores'];
}
```

because there's not `overall_scores`. You may have to alias it as `SELECT 1+COUNT(*) AS overall_scores FROM...` and do

```
$result=mysql_query("SELECT 1+COUNT(*) AS overall_scores FROM ...");
$data=mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
echo $data['overall_scores']; // Or $data['1+COUNT(*)'] if you did not alias it
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to change mysql_fetch_array() instead of mysql_fetch_assoc() look like this

```
$rank = mysql_query("SELECT 1+COUNT(*) AS overall_scores FROM `class_ranking` WHERE overall_scores > (SELECT overall_scores FROM `class_ranking` WHERE ref_id='$id')");
$finalArr = [];
While ($rk = mysql_fetch_assoc($rank)){
    $finalArr[] = $rk['overall_scores'];
}
echo '<pre>';
print_r($finalArr);
```

Comment: why use `mysql_fetch_assoc()`?

Comment: Because of you need to use associative array values

Comment: `mysql_fetch_array` returns both associative and num array. This answer should not be upvoted as it's definitely not the solution. 2 people before you have already stated to make an alias aswell...